# Simple Question regarding Java Web Start Applications

Tags: java

Can a Java application launched using Java Web Start perform read/write operations
on user's hard drive. I know that this is not the case with java script embedded
in a web page. Basically what I am asking are there any such restrictions with
a java application invoked using a web browser?

Kurt

I am having trouble using the {} to insert code

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///c:/Users/OPTRADER/" href="trader.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Optrader</title>
    <vendor>DS Software</vendor>
    <description>Optrader JNLP Demo </description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jar href="Optrader.jar"/>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="Optrader"/>
</jnlp>`
    { 

  
    Optrader
    DS Software
    Optrader JNLP Demo

Comment: Are you aware that Java Web Start downloads the program to the user's computer?  Did you read this? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html  What part of "full-featured applications" was confusing?  Could you update the question to show what part of this confused you?

Comment: I added the JNLP from your comment here - please check that your's really looks like this (I removed a `;` somewhere).

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can.  In the JNLP file for the application you can specify if the application has All permissions.  It can operate just like a normal Java desktop application.   The difference is that you need to sign the jars if you are going to grant the permission.  However, you have the ability to sign them yourself.

Comment: thanks jzd. Can I ask you please another quick question I have a jar file i have the xml file to create a jnlp but when I double click the xml in windows all i see is the xml code and no jnlp it's driving me mad what do i do to create the jnlp?

Comment: Is the xml file an ant build file?  If so you need to run ant to build the project using the xml file.   Or is the xml file the JNLP file?

Comment: the xml file is maybe an ant script that creates the jnlp. so you need to run it with ant.

Comment: thanks jzd all i have done is created an xml file using textpad like the one documented in Sun's tutorials in fact it is a very simple one. I save it as an xml - i though bu double clicking it it would generate a jnlp file? this is the xml file

Comment: If the XML file is supposed to be a JNLP file you need to save with a JNLP extension

Answer (score 1):

By default these applications run in a Sandbox to protect users from malicous code, so I'd say "no".

Comment: thanks trojanfoe so if  i have a java application that performs read/write operations are you saying that it is better to download the application from say my website and let them run it as desktop application?

Comment: I would say so yes, however this is just the default state; as jzd has pointed out the user can change this

Answer (score 1):

For a sand-boxed local file access with Webstart (and with JNLP-applets to, from Java 6, update 10, when the new plugin came out), use the services in the [javax.jnlp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html) package (linked from the [Webstart documentation page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/index.html).

In this case, a FileOpenService and/or FileSaveService lets the user confirm the action and select a file in a filechooser, and you then get a FileContents object, which you can then read from or write to.

You don't need special permissions for that, not even sign your code (but I think if you do, the confirmation dialog looks less intimidating, as it contains the information who wants this).

If you want to see how it looks like from user perspective, use our [Applet here](http://www.fencing-game.de/en/account.html) and select **custom picture**.

Comment: thanks guys how can i send my .xml code using this website? cannot produce the jnlp?

Comment: {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <jnlp spec="1.0+"

       codebase="file:///c:/Users/OPTRADER/"
       href="trader.jnlp">
       
  <information>

      <title>Optrader</title>

      <vendor>DS Software </vendor>

     <description>Optrader JNLP Demo </description>
              
     <offline-allowed/>

   </information>

    <resources>       
    
    <jar href="Optrader.jar"/>     

    <j2se version="1.6+"  

      href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>  
    </resources> 
     <application-desc main-class="Optrader"/> 

  </jnlp>}

Comment: Paulo can you help please really stuck when i double click this in Window i.e the file optrader.xml containing the code above it just displays the code and no .jnlp file is generated - I am new to all of this.

Comment: Add your XML to your original question, not to a comment here.  Withouth looking at the details (it is not really readable this way), you have a JNLP file here, it does not need to be "produced".

Comment: Sorry how do I add XML to original question? I will do but I am really confused what do you mean I have a jnlp file here? Will try and add to original question

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems that your problem is something completely different than in your original question.

To start your Webstart-application, save the XML file you have there under the name `trader.jnlp` in your directory `c:/Users/OPTRADER/`, and *then* double-click on it. If webstart is configured right and the jar file is also in the right place, it now should start your program.

If you get some error message saying that Windows does not now what to do with your file, then you should reinstall Java webstart (or your JRE/JDK).

If you get some error message from Webstart, add this message to your question (there is an *edit* link below it).

If your program runs and you have some other problem, describe the problem (also in your question).

Comment: thanks for your help I thought that by double clicking the .xml file this would then generate a .jnlp file which I then put into the same dir as my jar. My original question was based on the fact that I an weighing up the pros and cons of how I want to deliver my Java application as a desktop application or launched from my website (under construction) using a web browser. Sorry Paulo for my lack of knowledge I am new to all of this - thanks for your help.